# Document_Open() event does not fire on every computer

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a Word which is used for form filling. The users are filling what is asked and some macros runs depending on what they chose or where they click. This works fine.

I recently decided to make a newer version which countains some ComboBox that are filled when the document is opened. To do that, I used the `Document_Open()` event.

Now here is the part I don't get : On my side, every time I do open the document, the event is triggered and the ComboBox that should get filled are filled. The problem is, so far I asked some people to test it on their own computer with their Word. Both of them came back to me saying that the ComboBox weren't filled when the document was openned.

To be more specific let's go in the code itself :

In *ThisDocument*, I have multiple subs that works perfectly fine and this Document_Open() event which gives me trouble.

```
 Private Sub Document_Open()
     Application.Run ("Fill.ComboBox")
 End Sub
```

Here, **Fill** is the name of the Module which contains :

```
 Sub ComboBox()

     'Calling another Sub in this Module which adds the Items in the ComboBoxes
     'from what parameters it is given 

 End Sub
```

Now that this has been stated, why would it work on my side but not work when another user tries it from their computer ?

Miscorsoft Word Versions :

I myself use Microsoft Office Profesionnal 2013 and so are the two users that tested it. That being said, this is intended to be working on any Word liscense from 2007 up to the current versions.

Comment: Have a look at the macro security settings, it may not be fired.

Comment: I'll have to ask the users to check since I do not have acces to their computers. That being said, if they can use the other macros in the document doesn't it means they have their macro security settins to enabled ? (I asked them to enable them a while back with the first versions of the document)

Comment: I suspect the opposite: the event is firing before all the code is ready, so your Document_Open procedure gets skipped or possibly it does fire, but `fill.combobox` or some such thing doesn't exist yet. Try throwing a `Stop` or `msgbox` in the event procedure to test.

Comment: @Tim will do tomorrow and let you know. If you are right though, what do you suggest doing to make it fire properly ?

Comment: What kind of ComboBox is it? ActiveX or a Forms combo? Are the controls on a userform or just embedded in the document? If its Active X, you can use the GotFocus event to fill it.

Comment: It indeed is ActiveX ComboBoxes. They are embedded in the document, no user form. I'll take a look at the GotFocus event you just suggested and I'll be back to you on that tomorrow (out of town).

Comment: Went to see one of them to see the issues and it did work on her computer... Feeling like the problem is not in the code itself but a foot away from the screen... Jokes aside, I'll be back to you when I meet the last one.

Answer (score 1):

You can try in a module in your document:

```
Public Sub AutoOpen()
    ComboBox
End Sub
```

I just used this in a Word 2016 document to automagically run a macro. 
For documentation: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/286310/description-of-behaviors-of-autoexec-and-autoopen-macros-in-word